# Automatic Generate of Hreflangs

Tags: javascript, php, html, automation, hreflang

I would like to ask for a hand to create a code that automatically generates **hreflangs** on the web page with identical names (ex. /page123.php).

For example the page **[www.example.it/page123.php](http://www.example.it/page123.php)** has many versions in other languages.

Is it possible to automatically generate a code based on the link?

For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.it/page123.php" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.it/de/page123.php" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.it/en/page123.php" hreflang="en" />
```

etc..

```js
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = window.location.href;
```

```html
<p id="url"></p>
```

Comment: It is possible indeed. Please  show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: For now I have not structured any code. 
I tried to search online but I could not find anything and for this I created the post.

Comment: Please show some effort in solving this problem on your own :) I'm happy to help but I will not post the full solution without seeing some of your code.

Comment: I see it very difficult. I am a beginner. Thanks anyway.